# Complex operations using textboxes calculator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm not very expert to programming in wp7/c#. I'm trying to create a calculator of chemical compounds.
The application work on the basis of textboxes calculator...I did a sum of 3 textboxes with this code:

```
        {
           {
              {
                  try
                    {

                    double a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox14.Text);
                    double d = Convert.ToDouble(textBox15.Text);
                    double g = Convert.ToDouble(textBox16.Text);

                    textBox17.Text = (a + d + g).ToString();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

after I wanted to create a more complex operation in the same code, but with more textboxes and i tried:

```
            {
        {
            {
                try
                {
                    double a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox14.Text);
                    double d = Convert.ToDouble(textBox15.Text);
                    double g = Convert.ToDouble(textBox16.Text);
                    double b = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
                    double h = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
                    double k = Convert.ToDouble(textBox18.Text);
                    double l = Convert.ToDouble(textBox17.Text);
                    double m = Convert.ToDouble(textBox38.Text);

                    textBox17.Text = (a + d + g).ToString();
                    textBox19.Text = (h * a / k - l * b / k - m).ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

with this I wanted (after the sum and using this...watch "l" and textbox17) the second operation performed.....but doesn't work (I put the code in each textbox used).
is there a way (even alternative) to create such operations? If yes, how can I do this? Help me please!

EDIT

I tried in this way and it works perfectly, thanks Alex Ovechkin:

```
    textBox19.Text = ((h * a / k) - (l * b / K ) - m).ToString();
```

I did not know that C# perform in line operation without this mathematical rule: first multiplication and division and after addition and subtraction.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Is it not doing anything? Is it throwing an error? Is it giving you different results than you expect?

Comment: Are you entering numbers in all of the textboxes? Can you put catch (Exception ex) and tell us what the 'ex' exception is?

Comment: Many know that naming variables is one of the hardest problems in programming.  Hopefully these mean something to you and everyone reading your code because they have no value outside of your environment.

Comment: OMG!!!!!! `textBox38`??? please post a screenshot of what you need and we can give you the right way to implement that in XAML-based technologies (WP7 / WP8 / WinRT / Silverlight / WPF). If you can't post the image here, then upload it to imgur or something and paste a link to that.

Comment: it doesn't work because in the textbox19 not displayed nothing...yes i entering numbers in all textboxes.....yes now i upload something screenshot

Comment: +1 for sample code with screenshots...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have got division by zero, you catch an exception but do nothing with it, so nothing is displayed in your textbox